# Get referer URL from external redirect to my application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm new in React so will appreciate any help:

1. `www.google.com/home` my user is on this
2. Then gets redirected to my react app `www.app.com`

How do I get google.com or /home?

Perhaps:

```
{pathname} = useLocations();
pathname.match(google.com)
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can't redirect google to your site, since you can't run your scripts on google. Otherwise every site would just hijack a popular site to redirect to themselves

Comment: I don't need to redirect it. I send my users to an integration and after that integration they are sent back to my application. I'm trying to get the URL they are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I am aware of is to check [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

This does not work for every link, but if there is no `noreferrer` in the link to get to your app it should be fine. Since I don't know what you want to do with it, the code is quite generic:

```
const {referrer} = document;
if(referrer.includes("google.com")){
  // do something
}
```

Comment: referrer is undefined in the above, it doesn't work. I'm using react if that makes a difference.

Comment: according to the MDN page (and my experience) it should contain the referrer or be an empty string, never `undefined`:  "The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly"

Comment: Sorry yes I meant empty string: 

I found these as explanations for why this would happen - 
1. Users accessing the link from a bookmark, history or by typing the link manually do not have a referer.

2. IE has also been known to remove the referer in situations revolving around javascript. Such as window.open, window.location and even setting target="_blank" in anchors or meta refresh.

Comment: In that case you either navigated directly to your app or the link from the page before contains `noreferrer`. If you can't change that I doubt this is easily solvable (but since you mentioned google as the page before: links from google search results should always contain the referrer).